# Parser for COBOL written in JAVA

Tags: java, cobol

I wanna check write script to check MI(Maintainability Index) value for COBOL code.
For that i need a Parser written in JAVA for COBOL code.
Please help me in this

Comment: Try to be more specific about what kind of help you expect, or the close votes will accumulate

Comment: Its pretty clear he wants to know if there is a java based COBOL parser out htere that he can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at some "Java cobol parser" in a search engine ( [koopa](http://sourceforge.net/projects/koopa/) ). Also, consider "java lexer parser generator".

Answer (score 1):

There is one out there already:

http://mapage.noos.fr/~bpinon/a_cobol_parser.htm

Not sure of the quality or which particular dialect of COBOL you need to parse! But its a starting point.

Be warned though the normal criteria for maintainability are pretty much inverted when it comes to COBOL (e.g. Lots of small independant subroutines = Bad !).

Comment: Lots of small independant subroutines are a good thing in Cobol, just as they are in all other languages.  Common Cobol practice might still lean to giant monolithic programs, but that doesn't make it more maintainable.

Comment: Actually it does! The lack of type checking on subroutine calls menas its more reliable to "perform" a paragraph where all data types are already defined and known, than, calling a subroutine where you risk passing the wrong datatype.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project named NACA that can be a great source for your question :

http://code.google.com/p/naca/ :

NACA was about replacing an IBM mainframe under MVS/OS390 (zOS) with Intel servers on Linux. The project started in January 2003 and successfully ended on june 30, 2007. It was on purpose implemented in a 100% iso-functional way, i.e. without any functional / applicational improvement brought during the process of trans-coding itself and by the transcoding engine. 4 millions lines of COBOL were 100% automatically trans-coded toward their Java equivalent.